# TinyMCE with django, less options for editing

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I just installed TinyMCE and configured it to my app. But I see very less and only basic editing options in TinyMCE. There is no option to upload an image or even to adjust the size of the text. Have I configured it wrong or it really has limited options?
Here is the screenshot of the textfield with TinyMCE:
[image]

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
class blogpost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    publishdate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import blogpost
from django.db.models import TextField
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
class EntryAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title","publishdate")
    formfield_overrides = {TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})}}

admin.site.register(blogpost, EntryAdmin)
```

Comment: You'll need to configure TinyMCE to show more buttons on the toolbar. See [docs](http://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to change the "plugins" and "theme" of your tinymce config.

from the docs https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuration

> Configuration
>
> The application can be configured by editing the project’s settings.py
>   file.
>
> TINYMCE_JS_URL (default: settings.MEDIA_URL +
>   'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')
>
> ```
> The URL of the TinyMCE javascript file:
>
> TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_URL, "path/to/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")
> ```
>
> TINYMCE_JS_ROOT (default: settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'js/tiny_mce')
>
> ```
> The filesystem location of the TinyMCE files. It is used by the compressor (see below):
>
> TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "path/to/tiny_mce")
> ```
>
> TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG (default: {'theme': "simple", 'relative_urls':
>   False})
>       The default TinyMCE configuration to use. See the TinyMCE manual for all options. To set the configuration for a specific TinyMCE
>   editor, see the mce_attrs parameter for the widget.
>   TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER (default: False)
>       Whether to use the spell checker through the supplied view. You must add spellchecker to the TinyMCE plugin list yourself, it is not
>   added automatically. TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR (default: False)
>       Whether to use the TinyMCE compressor, which gzips all Javascript files into a single stream. This makes the overall download size 75%
>   smaller and also reduces the number of requests. The overall
>   initialization time for TinyMCE will be reduced dramatically if you
>   use this option. TINYMCE_FILEBROWSER (default: True if 'filebrowser'
>   is in INSTALLED_APPS, else False)
>       Whether to use the django-filebrowser as a custom filebrowser for media inclusion. See the official TinyMCE documentation on custom
>   filebrowsers.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> TINYMCE_JS_URL = 'http://debug.example.org/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js'
>
> TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
>         'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
>         'theme': "advanced",
>         'cleanup_on_startup': True,
>         'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10, }  TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
>
> TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
> ```